# Supplying my own Query Statement - Can it be done?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a Crystal 2008 report, and I'd like to provide it a T-SQL statement for data generation, instead of selecting and joining together tables. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In the Database Expert, after picking your connection, instead of choosing your tables, select "Add Command" and type your query in there.